# How can I get an int[] out of an Iterator?

Tags: java, collections

I have what amounts to an `Iterator<Integer>`... actually it's a `class Thing` that accepts a `Visitor<SomeObject>` and calls `visit()` for a subset of the `SomeObject`s it contains, and I have to implement `Visitor<SomeObject>` so it does something like this:

```
// somehow get all the Id's from each of the SomeObject that Thing lets me visit
public int[] myIdExtractor(Thing thing)
{
    SomeCollection c = new SomeCollection();
    thing.visitObjects(new Visitor<SomeObject>()
         {
              public void visit(SomeObject obj) { c.add(obj.getId()); }
         }
    );
    return convertToPrimitiveArray(c);
}
```

I need to extract an `int[]` containing the results, and I'm not sure what to use for `SomeCollection` and `convertToPrimitiveArray`. The number of results is unknown ahead of time and will be large (10K-500K). Is there anything that would be a better choice than using `ArrayList<Integer>` for `SomeCollection`, and this:

```
public int[] convertToPrimitiveArray(List<Integer> ints)
{
    int N = ints.size();
    int[] array = new int[N];
    int j = 0;
    for (Integer i : ints)
    {
        array[j++] = i;
    }
    return array;
}
```

Efficiency and memory usage are of some concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not too difficult to come up with a class that collects `int`s in an array (even if you are not using some library which does it for you).

```
public class IntBuffer {
    private int[] values = new int[10];
    private int size = 0;
    public void add(int value) {
        if (!(size < values.length)) {
            values = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(values, values.length*2);
        }
        values[size++] = value;
    }
    public int[] toArray() {
        return java.util.Arrays.copyOf(values, size);
    }
}
```

(Disclaimer: This is stackoverflow, I have not even attempted to compile this code.)

As an alternative you could use `DataOutputStream` to store the `int`s in a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

```
final ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
final DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(byteOut);
...
    out.writeInt(value);
...
out.flush();
final byte[] bytes = byteOut.toByteArray();
final int[] ints = new int[bytes.length/4];
final ByteArrayInputStream byteIn = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes);
final DataInputStream in = new DataOutputStream(byteIn);
for (int ct=0; ct<ints.length; ++ct) {
    ints[ct] = in.readInt();
}
```

(Disclaimer: This is stackoverflow, I have not even attempted to compile this code.)

Comment: you have a typo, btw: "values[size++] = value", not "- value"

Answer (score 1):

You could look at something like [pjc](http://pcj.sourceforge.net/) to handle this. That is a collections framework made for primitives.

Answer (score 0):

for benchmarking's sake I put together a test program using an LFSR generator to prevent the compiler from optimizing out test arrays. Couldn't download pjc but I assume timing should be similar to Tom's `IntBuffer` class, which is by far the winner. The ByteArrayOutputStream approach is about the same speed as my original `ArrayList<Integer>` approach. I'm running J2SE 6u13 on a 3GHz Pentium 4, and with approx 2<sup>20</sup> values, after JIT has run its course, the IntBuffer approach takes roughly 40msec (only 40nsec per item!) above and beyond a reference implementation using a "forgetful" collection that just stores the last argument to `visit()` (so the compiler doesn't optimize it out). The other two approaches take on the order of 300msec, about 8x as slow.

**edit:** I suspect the problem with the Stream approach is that there is the potential for exceptions which I had to catch, not sure.

(for arguments run PrimitiveArrayTest 1 2)

```
package com.example.test.collections;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class PrimitiveArrayTest {
    interface SomeObject {
        public int getX();
    }
    interface Visitor {
        public void visit(SomeObject obj);
    }

    public static class PlainObject implements SomeObject
    {
        private int x;
        public int getX() { return this.x; }
        public void setX(int x) { this.x = x; }  
    }

    public static class Thing
    {
        /* here's a LFSR        
         * see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_feedback_shift_register
         * and http://www.ece.cmu.edu/~koopman/lfsr/index.html
         */
        private int state;
        final static private int MASK = 0x80004;
        private void _next()
        {
            this.state = (this.state >>> 1) 
            ^ (-(this.state & 1) & MASK);
        }
        public Thing(int state) { this.state = state; }     
        public void setState(int state) { this.state = state; }

        public void inviteVisitor(Visitor v, int terminationPoint)
        {
            PlainObject obj = new PlainObject();
            while (this.state != terminationPoint)
            {
                obj.setX(this.state);
                v.visit(obj);
                _next();
            }
        }
    }

    static public abstract class Collector implements Visitor
    {
        abstract public void initCollection();
        abstract public int[] getCollection();
        public int[] extractX(Thing thing, int startState, int endState)
        {
            initCollection();
            thing.setState(startState);
            thing.inviteVisitor(this, endState);
            return getCollection();
        }
        public void doit(Thing thing, int startState, int endState)
        {
            System.out.printf("%s.doit(thing,%d,%d):\n",
                    getClass().getName(),
                    startState,
                    endState);
            long l1 = System.nanoTime();
            int[] result = extractX(thing,startState,endState);
            long l2 = System.nanoTime();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            sb.append(String.format("%d values calculated in %.4f msec ",
                    result.length, (l2-l1)*1e-6));
            int N = 3;
            if (result.length <= 2*N)
            {
                sb.append("[");
                for (int i = 0; i < result.length; ++i)
                {
                    if (i > 0)
                        sb.append(", ");
                    sb.append(result[i]);
                }
                sb.append("]");
            }
            else
            {
                int sz = result.length;
                sb.append(String.format("[%d, %d, %d... %d, %d, %d]",
                        result[0], result[1], result[2], 
                        result[sz-3], result[sz-2], result[sz-1]));
            }
            System.out.println(sb.toString());          
        }
    }

    static public class Collector0 extends Collector
    {
        int lastint = 0;
        @Override public int[] getCollection() { return new int[]{lastint}; }
        @Override public void initCollection() {}
        @Override public void visit(SomeObject obj) {lastint = obj.getX(); }
    }
    static public class Collector1 extends Collector
    {
        final private List<Integer> ints = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        @Override public int[] getCollection() {
            int N = this.ints.size();
            int[] array = new int[N];
            int j = 0;
            for (Integer i : this.ints)
            {
                array[j++] = i;
            }
            return array;           
        }
        @Override public void initCollection() { }
        @Override public void visit(SomeObject obj) { ints.add(obj.getX()); }
    }

    static public class Collector2 extends Collector
    {
        /*
         * adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167060
         * by Tom Hawtin
         */
        private int[] values;
        private int size = 0;
        @Override public void visit(SomeObject obj) { add(obj.getX()); }
        @Override public void initCollection() { values = new int[32]; }
        private void add(int value) {
            if (!(this.size < this.values.length)) {
                this.values = java.util.Arrays.copyOf(
                        this.values, this.values.length*2);
            }
            this.values[this.size++] = value;
        }
        @Override public int[] getCollection() {
            return java.util.Arrays.copyOf(this.values, this.size);
        }       
    }

    static public class Collector3 extends Collector
    {
        /*
         * adapted from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1167060
         * by Tom Hawtin
         */
        final ByteArrayOutputStream byteOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        final DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(this.byteOut);
        int size = 0;
        @Override public int[] getCollection()  {
            try
            {
                this.out.flush();
                final int[] ints = new int[this.size];
                final ByteArrayInputStream byteIn 
                    = new ByteArrayInputStream(this.byteOut.toByteArray());
                final DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(byteIn);

                for (int ct=0; ct<ints.length; ++ct) {
                    ints[ct] = in.readInt();
                }
                return ints;
            }
            catch (IOException e) { /* gulp */ }

            return new int[0]; // failure!?!??!
        }

        @Override public void initCollection() { }
        @Override public void visit(SomeObject obj) {
            try {
                this.out.writeInt(obj.getX());
                ++this.size;
            }
            catch (IOException e) { /* gulp */ }
        }       
    }
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        int startState = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
        int endState = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
        Thing thing = new Thing(0);
        // let JIT do its thing
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; ++i)
        {
            Collector[] collectors = {new Collector0(), new Collector1(), new Collector2(), new Collector3()};
            for (Collector c : collectors)
            {
                c.doit(thing, startState, endState);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -4):

Instead of convertToPrimitiveArray, you can use List.toArray(T[] a):

```
ArrayList<int> al = new ArrayList<int>();
// populate al
int[] values = new int[al.size()];
al.toArray(values);
```

For your other concerns, LinkedList might be slightly better than ArrayList, given that you don't know the size of your result set in advance.

If performance is really a problem, you may be better off hand-managing an int[] yourself, and using System.arraycopy() each time it grows; the boxing/unboxing from int to Integer that you need for any Collection could hurt.

As with any performance-related question, of course, test and make sure it really matters before spending too much time optimizing.

Comment: `ArrayList<int>` is illegal. And therefore you can't pass an `int[]` into `toArray(T[])`.

Comment: You can't have an ArrayList of primitive ints. It has to be Integers.

Comment: I almost suggested the same thing.  But then I remembered mmyers point.